# ruby on rails trying to sort by exact match first then partial matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

I have a pg database. I am using a search bar to look up a word in two columns, one english and one non-english. I would like the exact matches to show first then the rest after.

this is my word model

```
found = where("translation ~* ? OR english ILIKE ?",  "^#{result}", "%#{search}%").where('dialect_id IN (?)', dialect_ids)

found.sort { |x, y| x.english.length <=> y.english.length }
```

this is my word controller search

```
def search
    puts params[:search]
    puts params[:language_id]
    @words = Word.search(params[:search], params[:language_id])
    # we'll change word model to include language and keyword
    render jsonapi: @words
  end
```

I realize I have it trying to sort by length. I would like it sorted by exact match first then partial matches after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively use the `pg_trgm` (or `fuzzystrmatch` e.g.) extension.

Create a (reversible) migration to enable it.

```
class CreateExtensionPgTrgm < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    enable_extension('pg_trgm') unless extensions.include?('pg_trgm')
  end

  def down
    disable_extension('pg_trgm') if extensions.include?('pg_trgm')
  end
end
```

Then you can filter by similarity:

```
SELECT words.*
FROM words
WHERE similarity(translation, word) > 0.4 OR similarity(english, word) > 0.4
```

The default scale value is 0.3, so you can play there according to your needs.

ActiveRecord way would be:

```
Word.where('similarity(translation, :word) > 0.4 OR similarity(english, :word) > 0.4', word: word)
# or
Word
  .where('similarity(translation, ?) > 0.4', word)
  .or(Word.where('similarity(english, ?) > 0.4', word))
```

Comment: Alright! I think I got it. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Nice. Glad to help ;)